# setInterval() function is not working

Tags: javascript, html, css

According to my code , I should stop when I count up to 60% but the counter will continue counting higher than 60%. I should stop at 60%, but instead I count on forever! What should I do to solve this problem?

```js
 var i = 0;
 function counter(tag_name, precent, varname) {
     i++;
     $(tag_name).html(i + "%");
     if (i == precent) clearInterval(varname);
 }
 var p1 = setInterval(function () {
     counter("#p1", 60, p1);
 }, 50);
 var p2 = setInterval(function () {
     counter("#p2", 60, p2);
 }, 50);
var p3 = setInterval(function () {
     counter("#p3", 60, p3);
 }, 50);
```

```css
div {
    border:solid 1px black;
    margin:1px;
    width:50px;
    height:30p;
    float:left;
}
#m1, #m2, #m3 {
    width:200px;
    height:60px;
    float:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="m1">
    <div id="b1">d1</div>
    <div id="p1">%</div>
</div>
<div id="m2">
    <div id="b2">d2</div>
    <div id="p2">%</div>
</div>
<div id="m3">
    <div id="b3">d3</div>
    <div id="p3">%</div>
</div>
```

Comment: use >= percent instead of ==percent, it rolls overs after the 2nd and 3rd copy hit...

Comment: The problem is, that you use 1 variable I, and you call it 3 times, that's why you'll get 60, 61, and 62 as result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of issues there:

1. `clearInterval(varname);` will call `clearInterval` with the argument `varname`, which is the value of the variable you pass in *as of when you pass it*, not later when you're looking at it (because the value of, say, `p1`, is read and then passed into the function). Although you *could* fix that by using properties of an object and passing the property name, there's a better way.
2. All of your counters share the same `i` variable, so at the very least you can't stop at `i == precent` because only one of the three will ever see that. It also makes the counters increment oddly.
3. It's "percent," not "precent". :-)

I would use separate `i` variables, have `counter` manage things itself, and probably use a chain of `setTimeout` rather than `setInterval`:

```js
function counter(tag_name, percent) {
    var i = 0;

    run();

    function run() {
        i++;
        $(tag_name).html(i + "%");
        if (i < percent) {
            setTimeout(run, 50);
        }
    }
}
counter("#p1", 60);
counter("#p2", 60);
counter("#p3", 60);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="p1"></p>
<p id="p2"></p>
<p id="p3"></p>
```

But if you want them to share `i`, you could use properties as I mentioned earlier:

```js
var i = 0;
var handles = {};

function counter(tag_name, percent, propname) {
    i++;
    if (i >= percent) clearInterval(handles[propname]);
    if (i <= percent) $(tag_name).html(i + "%");
}
handles.p1 = setInterval(function () {
    counter("#p1", 60, "p1");
}, 50);
handles.p2 = setInterval(function () {
    counter("#p2", 60, "p2");
}, 50);
handles.p3 = setInterval(function () {
    counter("#p3", 60, "p3");
}, 50);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="p1"></p>
<p id="p2"></p>
<p id="p3"></p>
```

That works because in JavaScript, you can refer to a property using either dot notation and a *literal* property name (`obj.foo`), or brackets notation and a *string* property name (`obj["foo"]`).

I would tend to go with the first example, though.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, change `== precent` to `>= precent`
then, under `if (i >= precent) clearInterval(varname);`, add
`if (i >= precent) $(tag_name).html(precent + "%");`
This solves the problem and works as expected.

I have a fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/0rukk816/1/

Comment: While this answer may theoretically answer the question, [it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259), and provide the link for reference. Please add the relevant content directly to your answer, as it'll prevent link rot.

Answer (score 0):

change this line

```
if (i == precent) clearInterval(varname);
```

with the new one

```
if (i >= precent) clearInterval(varname);
```